# What's the use of an acknowledgement number without the ACK flag set?

Tags: tcp, protocol-theory, transport-protocol, layer4

Isn't it redundant if the ACK flag in the header isn't also on?

Do you ever *mix* an acknowledgement with a normal message - send data and acknowledge a message in the same TCP segment?

I feel like *one* is redundant - the ACK flag, or the Acknowledgement number (when the ack flag is off)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the use of an acknowledgement number without the ACK flag set?

That is explained in *[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793)* There is an overview for the reason, but further details if you read and understand the RFC:

> 2.6. Reliable Communication
>
> A stream of data sent on a TCP connection is delivered reliably and in
> order at the destination.
>
> Transmission is made reliable via the use of sequence numbers and
> acknowledgments. Conceptually, each octet of data is assigned a
> sequence number. The sequence number of the first octet of data in a
> segment is transmitted with that segment and is called the segment
> sequence number. ***Segments also carry an acknowledgment number which
> is the sequence number of the next expected data octet of
> transmissions in the reverse direction.*** When the TCP transmits a
> segment containing data, it puts a copy on a retransmission queue and
> starts a timer; when the acknowledgment for that data is received, the
> segment is deleted from the queue. If the acknowledgment is not
> received before the timer runs out, the segment is retransmitted.
>
> An acknowledgment by TCP does not guarantee that the data has been
> delivered to the end user, but only that the receiving TCP has taken
> the responsibility to do so.
>
> To govern the flow of data between TCPs, a flow control mechanism is
> employed.  The receiving TCP reports a "window" to the sending TCP.
> This window specifies the number of octets, starting with the
> acknowledgment number, that the receiving TCP is currently prepared to
> receive.

That explains the reason for the acknowledgment number, but the actual operation is explained in detail in the RFC.

> Do you ever mix an acknowledgement with a normal message - send data
> and acknowledge a message in the same TCP segment?

Yes, that is completely normal. For example, Data sent in response to a rquest can contain both the response and an acknowledgement of the request.

> I feel like one is redundant - the ACK flag, or the Acknowledgement
> number (when the ack flag is off)

No, you should really read and understand the RFC, which is the definition of TCP.

Comment: I don't feel you've actually answered my question. I understood what the acknowledgement number was for. *What's the ACK flag for*, if *all* segments contain an *valid* acknowledgement number

Comment: "_I understood what the acknowledgement number was for._" Apparently not. The ACK is to actually acknowledge, which is different than the acknowledgement number, which tells the other side what is the sequence number of the next expected segment. Those are two different things, so they are not redundant.

Comment: Is the acknowledgement number not used to determine what bytes being *acknowledged*

Comment: It's not that simple. Every segment, once a connection is established, will have an acknowledgment number that is the sequence number of the next expected segment. If the ACK flag is included in the segment, then the data being acknowledged can be calculated, and since it is cumulative, all the segments being acknowledged can be removed from the retransmission queue. Really, read the RFC to understand how the entire reliability mechanism works. It is too large to completely explain on this site.

Comment: Again, instead of redirecting me to a source in your answer, It would be more helpful to explain how it works and reference the website used. This simply isn't an answer to the question and I've noticed you doing it a lot. It may simply be you not wanting to baby me through the answer, but in that case you could simply leave a comment on the post with the source, of the form `see this post: http://..."

Comment: I _have_ explained it. I do not know what you do not understand. Also, since this is an archive, we are supposed to reference the relevant material, which I have done. The reason for having the acknowledgement number on every segment is clearly explained in the bold text in my answer, and if the ACK flag is included, then the segments being acknowledged can be calculated, but not having the ACK simply tells the other side the next segment you expect, but it is not acknowledging anything; two different purposes, not redundant.

Comment: The bold text didn't help, because I'm aware of what its saying. I'm saying someone answers posted could be reserved to comments

Comment: Your question is, "_What's the use of an acknowledgement number without the ACK flag set?_" That is clearly explained in the text. What is it about that that you do not understand? It is telling the other side that I expect Sequence Number X, next, from you. If the ACK flag is set, it says the same thing, but the other side knows that anything previous to that number is being acknowledged. The sequence number explains what is expected in the future, and the ACK acknowledges what was in the past. Those are two very different things, and not at all redundant.

Comment: `I do not know what you do not understand` -- Ron, if that is the case, then you shouldn't try to answer.

Comment: Look, Eddie, I am simply trying to clarify what the question is. This comment and the one removed seem to imply that you think I am being rude. Is the OP rude for asking a question about something he doesn't understand? If not, then why am I rude for asking about what I do not understand. It is plain that the ACK flag is for past data, while the acknowledgement number is about future data. If he can explain why he doesn't understand that, then I can edit the answer, but you seem to just want to stir up trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [RFC 793 *3.1 Header Format*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793#section-3.1)

> Acknowledgment Number:  32 bits
>
> If the ACK control bit is set this field contains the value of the
> next sequence number the sender of the segment is expecting to
> receive.  Once a connection is established this is always sent.

Put the other way around: when the ACK bit isn't set this field is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested, that is my opinion :)

I think that ACK bit is used not only to indicate that ACK sequence is relevant, but in connection opening and closing as a logic bit that tells us what to do next. They don't write this straight in RFC.

For example assume standard 3 way handshake between two stations A and B:

1. A sends SYN to B (CLOSED -> SYN SENT)
2. B receives SYN and sends SYN|ACK (LISTEN -> SYN RCVD)
3. A receives SYN|ACK and sends ACK (SYN SENT -> ESTABLISHED)
4. B receives ACK (SYN RCVD -> ESTABLISHED)

Now imagine that ACK bit is not important. Look at step 2. This would mess up whole procedure of establishing connection described in RFC. Station A in step 3 would receive SYN and think it's a simultaneous open and what next... ?

Comment: Hi i777, great contribution. But I have a possible answer to your question... Without the ACK flag, in Step 3 station A will receive a SYN with an Acknowledgement number that is +1 Station A's Initial Sequence Number. So even without the explicit ACK flag, Station A can assume the message sent from Station B is not a simultaneous open, but instead a response to Station A's SYN. . . In fact, you could set up logic that says any received SYN with a non 0 Acknowledgement # is a response, and not a new connection initiation request

Comment: The ACK flag is used to acknowledge past data, but the acknowledgement number is used to say what is expected in the future. Those are two completely different functions.

Comment: @Eddie you are correct. Maybe there are even more ways to do it, but TCP uses methods described in RFC. These methods make perfect logical sense.

Comment: @Ron, you are missing the point.  Without the Acknowledgement Number, how does the ACK flag acknowledge *the exact* past data that has been received?  /// @ i777 Agreed, current implementations use both, as directed by the RFC. But the OP asks an interesting question about a possible overlap in the functions of the ACK Number and the ACK Flag. I honestly don't know the answer, but am curious to see what comes up.

Comment: @Eddie, as I explained before, when a host sees the ACK flag, it knows that all data up to the acknowledgement number has been acknowledged, but the acknowledgement number, itself, is telling the host what the destination is expecting next. They are not redundant fas the OP suggests, but it seems that he simply doesn't understand that, even though I have explained it in various ways. The ACK flag is for past data, but the acknowledgement number is for future data, and that is clearly explained in the RFC.

Comment: @Eddie, every segment sent will have an acknowledgement number, per the RFC, explaining what is expected next, but not every segment will necessarily have an ACK. The OP also asked about including data with an ACK flag, and that is fine, too.